# Error al realizar la compilación java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, mvc, javafx

Esto es mi fxml llamado FXMLVistafx.ml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="249.0" prefWidth="425.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="mvvm.Vista">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="ta" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="58.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="tb" layoutX="105.0" layoutY="95.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <Button layoutX="36.0" layoutY="138.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSuma" text="Suma" />
      <TextField fx:id="tsalida" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="178.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
      <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="62.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="58.0" text="Ingrese A:" />
      <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="58.0" text="Ingrese B:" />
      <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="182.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="86.0" text="El resultado es:" />
      <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="263.0" text="SUMA DE DOS NUMEROS">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button layoutX="105.0" layoutY="138.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleResta" text="Resta" />
      <Button layoutX="166.0" layoutY="138.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleMultiplicacion" text="Multiplicacion" />
      <Button layoutX="281.0" layoutY="138.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleDivision" text="Division" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Esta clase es mi main

```
package mvvm;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;

public final class Main extends Application {

    public static void run() {
        launch();
    }

  

    @Override
    public void start( final Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("MVVM");

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLVista.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        //getController() no devuelve el controlador sino la Vista
        // si queremos que el controlador sea independiente de la GUI.
        Vista view = loader.getController();

        VistaModelo viewModel = new VistaModelo();
        view.setVistamodelo(viewModel);
        Modelo model = new Modelo();
        viewModel.setModelo(model);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Main.run();
    }

}
```

Esta es mi clase modelo

```
package mvvm;

public class Modelo {
    private double a;
    private double b;

    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(double a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public double getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(double b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public double sumar(){
        return this.a + this.b;
    }
    public double resta(){
        return this.a - this.b;
    }
    public double multiplicar (){
        return this.a * this.b;
    }
    public double division(){
        return this.a / this.b;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase Vista

```
package mvvm;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Vista {
    private VistaModelo viewmodel;
    
    @FXML
    private TextField ta;
    @FXML
    private TextField tb;
    @FXML
    private TextField tsalida;
    private TextField tsalida2;
    private TextField tsalida3;
    private TextField tsalida4;
    
    public void setVistamodelo(VistaModelo vm) {
         viewmodel = vm;
         ta.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewmodel.getentradaA());
         tb.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewmodel.getentradaB());
         tsalida.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewmodel.salidaSuma());
         tsalida2.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewmodel.salidaResta());
         tsalida3.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewmodel.salidaMultiplicacion());
         tsalida4.textProperty().bindBidirectional(viewmodel.salidaDivision());
    }
    
     @FXML
    private void handleSuma(ActionEvent event){
        viewmodel.salida();
    }
@FXML
    private void handleResta(ActionEvent event){
        viewmodel.salida2();
    }
@FXML
private void handleMultiplicacion(ActionEvent event){
        viewmodel.salida3();
    }
@FXML
    private void handleDivision(ActionEvent event){
        viewmodel.salida4();
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase VistaModelo

```
package mvvm;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty; import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class VistaModelo {

    private Modelo modelo;
    private StringProperty a;
    private StringProperty b;
    private StringProperty suma;
    private StringProperty resta;
    private StringProperty multiplicacion;
    private StringProperty division;

    public Modelo getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(Modelo modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public StringProperty getentradaA() {
        if (a == null) {
            a = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "a", "0");
        }
        return a;
    }

    public StringProperty getentradaB() {
        if (b == null) {
            b = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "b", "0");
        }
        return b;
    }

  
    public StringProperty salidaSuma() {
        if (suma == null) {
            suma = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "suma", "0");
        }
        return suma;
    }
       public StringProperty salidaResta() {
        if (resta == null) {
            resta = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "resta", "0");
        }
        return resta;
    }
    public StringProperty salidaMultiplicacion() {
        if (multiplicacion == null) {
            multiplicacion = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "multiplicacion", "0");
        }
        return suma;
    }
    public StringProperty salidaDivision() {
        if (division == null) {
            division = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "division", "0");
        }
        return division;
    }

    private void setSalida(String output) {
        salidaSuma().set(output);
    }
    private void setSalida2(String output) {
        salidaResta().set(output);
    }

    private void setSalida3(String output) {
        salidaMultiplicacion().set(output);
    }

    private void setSalida4(String output) {
        salidaDivision().set(output);
    }


    public void salida() {
       
        String inputa = getentradaA().get();
        String inputb = getentradaB().get();
        modelo.setA(Double.parseDouble(inputa));
        modelo.setB(Double.parseDouble(inputb));
        String stringsuma = String.valueOf(modelo.sumar());
        setSalida(stringsuma);
    }
    public void salida2() {
       
        String inputa = getentradaA().get();
        String inputb = getentradaB().get();
        modelo.setA(Double.parseDouble(inputa));
        modelo.setB(Double.parseDouble(inputb));
        String stringresta = String.valueOf(modelo.resta());
        setSalida(stringresta);
    }
    public void salida3() {
       
        String inputa = getentradaA().get();
        String inputb = getentradaB().get();
        modelo.setA(Double.parseDouble(inputa));
        modelo.setB(Double.parseDouble(inputb));
        String stringmultiplicacion = String.valueOf(modelo.multiplicar());
        setSalida(stringmultiplicacion);
    }
    public void salida4() {
       
        String inputa = getentradaA().get();
        String inputb = getentradaB().get();
        modelo.setA(Double.parseDouble(inputa));
        modelo.setB(Double.parseDouble(inputb));
        String stringdivision = String.valueOf(modelo.division());
        setSalida(stringdivision);
    }

}
```

Estoy intentando realizar una calculadora con el entorno javafx y con la estructura mvvc. Espero puedan ayudarme dado que aún no logro encontrar el error, gracias de antemano.

Al final me muestra lo siguiente en error:
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method
Exception running application mvvm.Main

Answer (score 0):

Añadí en las propiedades en `run vm options` la recomendación que encontré en YouTube.

Ahora solo me muestra un solo error que es el siguiente.

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --module-path
```

Comment: Si quieres agregar algo, edita la pregunta. Si ya has solucionado todos los problemas que tuviste, puedes publicar el procedimiento que seguiste.